# Avoiding tightly coupled class definitions in Python for has-a relationships

Tags: object-oriented, python, class

I have the following code:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, my_id):
        self.my_id = my_id
        self.color = color
        self.brand = brand

        self.get_color()
        self.get_brand()

    def get_color():
        return requests.get('https://example.com/{}/color'.format(self.my_id))

    def get_brand():
        return requests.get('https://example.com/{}/brand'.format(self.my_id))

def get_description(car):
    return 'My {} is {}'.format(car.brand, car.color)

def get_color(car):
    return 'My car is {}'.format(car.color)

def main():
    c = Car(123)
    print get_description(c)
```

It works quite well by first initializing a `Car` object that gathers all necessary data, and then allowing me to work with that data through first class functions.

However, I'd like to move all those functions into a separate class `Description`. This class, because it uses a bunch of data from Car, would be initialized as:

```
class Description(object):
    def __init__(self, car):
        self.car = car
        self.description_text = description_text
        self.color_text = color_text
```

where the `car` instance is passed as an argument to the `Description` object on instantiation.

I was told, however, that this approach is not the best since the two classes are now tightly coupled.

How should this example be reworked to use two classes? Should `Description` inherit the data from `Car`? Should I instantiate `Description` by passing all data from `Car`?

Comment: What's the API of the Description class, and how do you plan on using these classes? The obvious alternative to me is to use pure methods like `Description.getColor(car)` where the car is an argument and not a piece of state, but that's not always the best move. (also, resource requests are considered off-topic here, so I've edited out that last part of your question)

Comment: The planned use is to create an instance of car, which is loaded with all data. Then create a Description of said instance, and call various methods of that instance. Sorry about the resource request (and to risk another OT question, where should have I asked this?).

Comment: You can ask for resources on Reddit and other kinds of less strict Q&A sites. You can also try the site [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). By the way, how does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reworking the classes with a mixin and properties

> How should this example be reworked to use two classes? Should
>   Description inherit the data from Car? Should I instantiate
>   Description by passing all data from Car?

This is actually a great use-case for the has-a relationship of a mixin and properties. Don't prefix methods that execute immediately with `get`, use `@property` instead.

```
class Description_Mixin(object):
    """mixin assumes you have a brand and color"""

    @property
    def brand_and_color_description(self):
        return 'My {} is {}'.format(self.brand, self.color)

    @property
    def type_and_color_description(self):
        return 'My {} is {}'.format(type(self).__name__.lower(), self.color)
```

Don't use properties for the request methods, use regular methods to signify that this is a function that can (and will) take time to complete. Here, the code semantically says that the car "has-a" description.:

```
class Car(Description_Mixin):
    def __init__(self, my_id):
        self.my_id = my_id
        self.color = self.get_color()
        self.brand = self.get_brand()

    def get_color(self):
        return requests.get('https://example.com/{}/color'.format(self.my_id))

    def get_brand(self):
        return requests.get('https://example.com/{}/brand'.format(self.my_id))
```

And usage:

```
def main():
    c = Car(123)
    print c.brand_and_color_description
```

And you can reuse your mixin for other types that need those kinds of descriptions.

## Follow up - Lazy loading the attributes:

> If I want to have cli options that only return specific parts of the description, there is no need to load up all the resources for Car. For example, if I want to, based on a cli option, only get a car's type_and_color_description, there is no need to call get_brand(). Is there a way to modify this code to account for that (i.e. not assume I have all the data from Car)?

This is a matter of logistics. Here's an implementation that does this, but it makes the return of the color and brand attributes slow on the first retrieve:

```
class Car(Description_Mixin):
    def __init__(self, my_id):
        self.my_id = my_id

    @property
    def color(self):
        try:
            return self._color
        except AttributeError:
            self._color = requests.get(
              'https://example.com/{}/color'.format(self.my_id))
            return self._color

    @property
    def brand(self)
        try:
            return self._brand
        except AttributeError:
            self._brand = requests.get(
              'https://example.com/{}/brand'.format(self.my_id))   
            return self._brand
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! And one more follow-up Q, if I want to have cli options that only return specific parts of the description, there is no need to load up all the resources for Car. For example, if I want to, based on a cli option, only get a car's `type_and_color_description`, there is no need to call `get_brand()`. Is there a way to modify this code to account for that (i.e. not assume I have all the data from Car)?

Comment: @mart1n I think I got your followup.